# Why won't dplyr load on RStudio?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm fairly new to R. I'm using RStudio on Windows 10 for a class and I got this when trying to load dplyr after installing it:

```r
> install.packages("dplyr")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/samot/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/dplyr_1.0.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1334630 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\samot\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUv0uns\downloaded_packages
> library(dplyr)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘utf8’
```

Not quite sure how to get it to run. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The *"there is no package called"* is a clear and the sole indication of something not right, and it is among R's more intuitive error messages (there are plenty of obscure ones). Just like you started that session with the understanding that `dplyr` was not installed and available, you should now attack that error message with the same mindset, replacing "dplyr" with "utf8" in your thinking.

Comment: Great explanation! Now I realize I have to install the missing package. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can install the package that is needed

```
 install.packages('utf8')
```

Or another option is to specify the `dependencies` as TRUE to install all the necessary packages

```
install.packages('dplyr', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still learning. So this is great feedback. Appreciate it.